# Asus X540S / Ubuntu 10.16 Headphones not working

Tags: headphones

Having spent many hours trying all (or as many as I can find) 'solutions' on various sites including this page I still cannot properly get the headphones to work independent of the speakers. The speakers are working correctly. I can have the headphones and speakers working together but it is still impossible to have the headphones work independently and show in the top bar as 'headphones'only.

All methods seemingly exhausted are there any further ideas from anyone please or is Ubuntu going to issue software that gets over the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have the same laptop as you and also struggled with the same problem.  After(also) trying many hours worth of technical fixes, none of which worked. I finally downloaded the GNOME Alsa Mixer. As soon as I loaded it, it showed the headphones as being muted. I unchecked the "Mute" box, and they instantly worked! No restart necessary, not fancy .conf file editing. I hope this helps you out as well.